# Android login and authenticate facebook user into a backendless mbaas application

Tags: android, facebook, backendless

I have done upto the code below and can succesfully authenticate and login Facebook user.

I have compile `'com.backendless:backendless:3.0.15.1'` in my build gradle.

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
//        mDialog.dismiss();

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.e("response: ", response + "");

                        user = new User();
                        user.facebookID = object.optString("id");
                        user.name = object.optString("name");
                        user.email = object.optString("email");
                        user.gender = object.optString("gender");
                        user.locale = object.optString("locale");

                        Utils.setCurrentUser(user, LoginActivity.this);

                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in as " + user.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, locale, birthday, picture.width(80).height(80)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.i(TAG, "LoginButton FacebookCallback onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "LoginButton FacebookCallback onError:: "+error.getMessage());
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception:: "+error.getStackTrace());
    }
};
```

Comment: What code below? And if you have successfully done what you were trying to do, why are you even posting here?

Comment: the code has refused to format

Comment: That would be because you clicked the "bold" button instead of the "code" button. You also seemed to somehow manage to lose all indentation in the process. I'm not going to re-indent the entire code for you, so paste it in and click the `{}` button this time.

Comment: @ Matti Virkkunen-need to send the data to backendless

Comment: @ Matti Virkkunen-it's better now though it has left "private FacebookCallback mCallBack = new FacebookCallback() { @Override public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { // mDialog.dismiss(); " unformatted at the top.

Comment: Code is all formatted now

Comment: I know. I formatted the little bit you missed.

Comment: Thanks a pile @ Matti Virkkunen. I want to use Facebook SDK and not the Backendless SDK.